# Set orientation of moving object towards it movement direction without using rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` (camera) which is moving on the spline (using a library). I want to set its orientation towards its movement. What I mean is, the object should be looking in the direction that it is moving. I tried some things to achieve this, but I was unsuccessful. Here are my attempts:

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position);
```

I have also tried this

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward);
```

Comment: Just use "LookAt".  Never use quaternions for any reason.

Comment: HI JOE I USED LOOK AT BUT EACH TIME IT GET NEW VECTOR3 TRANSFORM IT PRODUCE JERK EFFECTS

Comment: state which spline software you are using.  most of them INCLUDE a "looking forward" feature

Comment: megaShape's MegaTrainFollow script

Comment: honestly your best bet is to ask them.  they are quite friendly and you paid a lot for it.  just email them, or check the forum for it.

Comment: Thanks i already asked him on forum but can't you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `transform.position` (a point in space) nor `transform.forward` (the direction an object is already facing) will necessarily give you the direction an object is moving in.

For an object with a `RigidBody`, you'd access this through the `velocity` variable - but since it sounds like you're using a proprietary spline library and have no access to the object's actual movement direction, you may need to keep track of it yourself.

The simplest solution (if the library really doesn't provide movement information), is to store the object's present position and previous position each frame, and manually calculating the delta position (aka. The distance travelled between the frames) to find the velocity vector. For example:

```
public class MovingObject : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 prevPosition;

    void Start() {
        // Starting off last position as current position
        prevPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update() {
        // Calculate position change between frames
        Vector3 deltaPosition = transform.position - prevPosition;

        if (deltaPosition != Vector3.zero) {
            // Same effect as rotating with quaternions, but simpler to read
            transform.forward = deltaPosition;
        }
        // Recording current position as previous position for next frame
        prevPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hi Serlite thanks for valueable answer direction is not fine if i press the vertical key to move my camera but direction become change as i stop input.

Comment: Thankyou so much it took 3 days to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - currentPosition);
```

where `currentPosition` is the position on the spline where your game object is right now (before applying the transformation `transform`).

Keep in mind that `Quaternion.LookRotation()` does not expect the position to look at but the *direction* where to look instead. See the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) and [FAQ](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/534907/difficulty-understanding-lookrotation.html).

Comment: thanks for input! but transform.position and currentPosition both are same. isn't it?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan, hmm... can you show us how you change `transform.position` to make the game object move along the spline?

Comment: something like this transform.position = car.cp + car.carriageOffset;

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan, well somehow you have to calculate the vector between the old and the new position and use this as the argument for `Quaternion.LookRotation`.

Comment: this is also valuable answer

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you should use your movement direction: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection)`, as `transform.forward` is already the objects' orientation.

If you do not know/have access to the objects' current movement direction but you know the target position, you can rotate towards the target position: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position)`

Comment: The vector with which you are moving the camera. (Like `camera.position = camera.position + movementVector`)

Comment: let me find how it is working acutally i dont how object is moving as i am using third party package to move cam on spline

Comment: movementDirection should be the position so what is the different b/w transform.position and movementDirection?

Comment: movementDirection should be the direction in which the camera is moving. The transform.position is translated to the next position (e.g. in each update call) utilizing the movement direction vector. For example: If the camera is moving sideways, the movement direction could be transform.right.

Comment: how can i find the direction? is this rotation

Comment: does that package provide some sort of documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112266/discussion-between-mohammad-faizan-khan-and-xyle).