# Unity3D character facing in the direction it’s moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game, it contains planetary gravity, how would I be able to make the player look in the direction it’s moving, would be helpful if I could insert it to my movement code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;

private Vector3 moveDirection;

void Update()
{
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) method? You could pass it your `(moveDirection + gameObject.transform.position)` and it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting orientation of moving object towards it movement direction, without a rigidbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295745/setting-orientation-of-moving-object-towards-it-movement-direction-without-a-ri)

Comment: It would make sense to use `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` or ←  → to turn or control the direction and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` or ↑ ↓ to control the movement.

Comment: @Paul-Jan The link is says "without a rigidbody". OP is using rigidbody.

Comment: @Programmer Regardless of the title specifics, the accepted answer also mentions how to do this with a RigidBody. But you are right, removed the close suggestion.

Comment: The answer mentioned rigidbody and velocity but didn't show how to actually do it. The solution it has is for non rigidbody objects. By the way [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) is supposed to be used not velocity as mentioned in that answer.

Comment: The movement I'm using now works fine but I'm kind of confused as to what you want me to put in my code, i want to rotate the player not the camera

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this script is attached to the object you want to have point at its movement direction, try this.

```
void Update()
{
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
    Vector3 lookDirection = moveDirection + gameObject.Transform.Position;
    gameObject.Transform.LookAt(lookDirection);
}
```

Because your moveDirection is normalized, you have to add it to your current position in order to get the moveDirection in the object's local space. Then you can `LookAt()` it to point towards it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the direction you're moving by using the rigidbody's velocity.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity);
```

If you want a smoothed transition:

```
Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: This works except im looking to rotate the player, not the camera

Comment: This should rotate the player unless your `PlayerMovementScript` is attached to the camera, which doesn't make alot of sense. However it should be a simple to fix even if that's the case.

Comment: could it be that my camera is attached or the player instead of having a follow script.

Comment: What do you mean? Basically as long as this script is attached to the player itself it should work as expected.